# how to retrieve the actual shared object local path

Tags: flash

I have prepared a login screen. Using shared object I have saved username and password. Now I want to know the sol path. Is there any way to actually retrieve the shared object local path. like  **C:\Documents and Settings[userName]\Application Data\Macromedia\Flash Player#SharedObjects\XXXXX\localhost\text.sol**?

Answer (score 2):

No you can't retrieve the actual path to a sol file in code. Security concerns.